# string a Date js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, string, date

el problema que tengo es que soy bastante nuevo, y en este caso, si fuera posible me gustaría respuesta exacta a este problema, porque tengo que realizar esto asi para poder continuar con el proyecto.
El caso es que de un servicio REST yo traigo un gregoriancalendar y recibo algo como esto en el lado del front.
Estoy usando VUejs

```
2020-04-15T08:30:00.000+0000
```

Bien, pues ahora necesito esto en formato new Date(), lo cual no se como pasarlo o como hacer para crear un Date con ese String, o en este formato tambien me valdría

```
2020-4-25 7:30
```

No se si alguien puedira ayudarme porque no tengo ni idea de como hacer esto y llevo tiempo parado por este problemilla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para resolver ese problema, podes realizar lo siguiente:

```
const tiempo = new Date('2020-04-15T08:30:00.000+0000');
```

Una vez realizado eso podes acceder a los metodos del tipo Date, por ejemplo:

- Si queres acceder al dia: tiempo.getDay();
- Si queres acceder la hora: tiempo.getHours();

y asi podes segir accediendo a los distintos metodos. [Aca](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) podes ver todos los metodos disponibles.

si realizas con console.log(tiempo), te devolveria algo asi:

> Wed Apr 15 2020 05:30:00 GMT-0300 (Argentina Standard Time)

Comment: dios era una tonteria pero verdaderamente no tenia ni idea de como hacerlo, muchas gracias por tu respuesta

Comment: Tambien puedes usar new Date('2020-04-15T08:30:00.000+0000').toLocaleString('es')